# GPS location after permission not working (SDK 23) android studio

Tags: android, android-gps

I have this class that i have created , where have i need to put my last location?

```
public class DescriptionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    TextView t;
    Button up;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    LocationServices mLastLocation;
    private static final int PERMS_REQUEST_CODE=123;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hr__description);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.hr_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_clear_white_24dp);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_boaz);
        up=(Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                .build();
        if(hasPermission())
        {
            getGPS();
        }
        else {
            requestPerms();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMS_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // All good!
                } else {
                   Log.d("bobbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","boazboabzobaob");
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    private void getGPS() {
        up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
    }

    private boolean hasPermission(){
            int res=0;
            String[] permissions=new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
            for(String params:permissions)
            {
                res=checkCallingOrSelfPermission(params);
                if(!(res==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void requestPerms(){
            String[] permissions=new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            {
             requestPermissions(permissions,PERMS_REQUEST_CODE);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, PERMS_REQUEST_CODE);
            }

        }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }
}
```

i tried to activate GPS and it always want me to check permissions
how to fix it?
looked on many examples on the internet and i have succeed to get dialog to activate GPS device but when i try to get location i have problem

Comment: Can you post Error Dialog ?

Comment: i not have any error just he ask me to add permissions

Comment: Which permission ?

Comment: And He Who is that?

Comment: Did you add the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission in your manifest file as well?

Comment: yes i i added ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  to my manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you want to make a connection to one of the Google APIs provided
>   in the Google Play services library (such as Google Sign-In, Games, or
>   Drive), you need to create an instance of GoogleApiClient ("Google API
>   Client"). The Google API Client provides a common entry point to all
>   the Google Play services and manages the network connection between
>   the user's device and each Google service.

- Automatically manage your connection to Google Play services.
- Perform   synchronous and asynchronous API calls to any of the Google
  Play    services.
- Manually manage your connection to Google Play services in    those
  rare cases where this is necessary.

> Add this to manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms.location.sample.basiclocationsample" >

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

> Add this code in your activity

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build()
 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: where i need to insert this code? on the OnCreate method?

Comment: and i do not have Drive.API it not recognized

Comment: when i add this code
 public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
          
        }
    }

Comment: i added this code but still i get message (call requested permissions which may be rejected by the user)

Answer (score 0):

> In onCreate Method in your activity

Comment: i do not have Drive.API it not recognized